# Rblpapi: overriding prices

Tags: r, bloomberg

I am trying to use Rblpapi to calculate bond analytics for a (large) number of bonds. I'd like to supply my own prices; in Excel, it is still possible using the old blp() function.

In Rblpapi, bdp() accepts overrides, but only the identical one for the whole set of securities. For example, I can set

```
overrides=c("SETTLE_DT"="20160620")
```

Obviously, it is possible to loop through all the securities, overriding the price for each one. Is there a better / faster to supply a vector of override values for one field?

Comment: The underlying API doesn't support multiple overrides so if Rblpapi has something like what you are asking, it will essentially loop over the securities like you suggest,

Comment: @assylias: Thanks, yes, looks like looping over the range of securities, one way or another, is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Using either `for()` or `apply()`, predictably, produces about the same result. Sending multiple separate requests to Bloomberg is very slow, but still better than running this in Excel.

Thanks!